# Azure AD B2E(Business to Employee) for single tenant configure in .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I Want to configure Azure AD B2E to .Net core application.For single tenant with in the organization.
For that  want to generate ID_token & Access token using the Azure tenant ID,client ID,secret key,scope.

Answer (score 0):

For how to generate ID_token & Access token using the Azure tenant ID,client ID,secret key,scope (without user credential), you will be interested in [client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow).

Call `POST /{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token` endpoint like this:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant id}/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id={client id of your Azure AD app}
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default
&client_secret={client secret of your Azure AD app}
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

You could refer to these [Azure Active Directory with ASP.NET Core Samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/azure-active-directory/?view=aspnetcore-3.1).